# JavaScript - doing something wrong with a String prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to create a custom string method.

I'm not sure how to get the value of the string, that the method is attached to, passed to the function and back.

```
function testPrototyping(passedVar) {
    passedVar += " reason why this is not working";
    return passedVar;
}

String.prototype.testMethod = testPrototyping;
var myVar = "some";
var myVar2;

// 1. This works but is not what I want:
myVar2 = myVar.testMethod(myVar);

// 2. This is what I want but doesn't work:
myVar2 = myVar.testMethod();

// 3. Wondering if this should work also:
myVar2 = testMethod(myVar);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers on "this". But with my complex real functions, what is the syntax to get "this" to be processed by everything I'm doing in the function?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. The scales have been lifted from my eyes. I now completely grok the nature of "this"! (Pretty much.) Unfortunately I can't vote any of you up as I have "no reputation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this` like here:

```
function testPrototyping() {
    var text = this;

    text = text.trim();

    text + " reason why this is not working";

    return text;
}
```

String.prototype.testMethod = testPrototyping;

"StackOverflow".testMethod()

The Keyword `this` inside a Prototype Method Refers to a Constructor instance. You can read more about ["this"](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/) here.

Comment: For the "this" produced by my method call here... How do I assign the string value of "this" to a variable inside the function. Then do a string.slice() on the variable. Then assign the result of that back to "this". Then return "this" to my method call?

Comment: I updated my example, you can just assign `this` to a variable, and then return it when you are done manipaluting it.

Comment: Thanks -- that's the practical solution I need. I'm curious though theoretically whether "return text" here is secretly assigning "text" as a value of "this" to be passed back to the calling method...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refer to the current string, you can use the `this` keyword:

```
function testPrototyping() {
    return this + " reason why this is not working";
}
```

You can however not assign anything to `this`. So `this += "..."` wouldn't work.

Comment: This is my question now... how to assign everything to "this" when I can't assign anything to "this" :)

Comment: Well why do you want to assign to `this`. Your example indicates that you want to assign the result to a new variable `myVar2`: `myVar2 = myVar.testMethod();`. Or do you want to change the value of `myVar` as well? Because this is not possible without directly referring to this variable by name.

Answer (score 0):

The Object wrapper `testPrototyping` will be called on is available via `this` inside `testPrototyping`. The actual underlying string of a String Object wrapper is available via the `valueOf()` method:

```
String.prototype.showStuff = function() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.valueOf());
  console.log(this + ' proves that conversion is done automatically');
  console.log(typeof this, 'but it is not ok in every situation');
};
var myVar = "test";

myVar.showStuff();
/* results (Chrome 32):
String {0: "t", 1: "e", 2: "s", 3: "t", length: 4, formatUnicorn: function, truncate: function, splitOnLast: function, contains: function…}
test
test proves that conversion is done automatically
object but it is not ok in every situation 
*/
```

Comment: I found the source of [unicorns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207128/what-is-formatunicorn-for-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you want because strings are immutable in javascript. It means that you can't change a string without creating a new one.

Depending on what you really need to achieve, you can use another object to "hide" the real string :

```
var MyString = function(s) {
    this.s = s;
};

MyString.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.s;
};

MyString.prototype.testMethod = function() {
   this.s += " reason why this is working";
};

var myVar = new MyString("some");
alert(myVar); // "some"
myVar.testMethod();
alert(myVar); // "some reason why this is working"
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now that "this" is a read-only object/thingy, but that values can be assigned to properties of it.